# How to put a Bar button item to the bottom of a toolbar?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitoolbar

I have a toolbar at the top of my app. I changed the height programmatically to make it a bit bigger.

```
    var constH = NSLayoutConstraint(item: toolbar, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height,
    relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: nil, 
    attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 64)
    toolbar.addConstraint(constH)
```

But now I have the problem when I add bar button items via storyboard, it automatically centers them vertically. Only the standard items stay at the bottom. How to solve?

[Please answer in Swift]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should hook up your bar button items using IBOutlets, then you can easily add spacing using edge insets:

`barButton.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0,10,0,0)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this for programmatically added items as well: (Code in Swift3)

```
let search = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "Search"), style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
search.imageInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(10, 0, 0, 0)
navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = search
```